# Child-class unique static variables: declared by parent, initialized by children, and auto-cloned static methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I'm trying to setup a way for child classes to have access to a static variables, for use in static methods.

Below is some code that outlines the sort of structure I need to support.

```cs
abstract class Shape{
  static abstract int sides;

  public static Shape CreateFromFile(string filename){
    ... reads a number of sides from a file, and returns the appropriate shape ..
  }
}

class Pentagon : Shape{
  static int sides = 5;
}

class Hexagon : Shape{
  static int sides = 6;
}
```

This does not compile, as static abstract fields or properties are not supported. I've found that altering the value in the child class' constructor will alter the original value, as no copy of static fields are made for new classes, so that is not an option.

Is there any option here other than rewriting it all in non-static form? This would require a lot of repeated code, as the methods don't have any functionality specific to the class.

Comment: Add a `GetNumberOfSides` property to the base class. Each implementing class can implement it as they see fit. Will it be a bit of extra work? Yes - but no more than 10 minutes work I would guess.

Comment: Generics could also be used (since the `static` will be scoped to the type of the generic) - but I think my first suggestion is simpler and more understandable.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. First, why would you even want an abstract static? So anyway, having it as static doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @mjwills That's one solution I had tried, but as the implementation for each class will be identical I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: I'd argue the answer you chose is _less_ clean than my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can use the `new` keyword in the child classes to intentionally hide the parent static property. And in the parent abstract class you throw `NotImplementedException`, this way you trick the compiler that doesn't allow static properties in the interfaces (However interfaces enforce compile-time check). Please check below code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle.Sides = 4;
        Pentagon.Sides = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(Rectangle.Sides); // 4
        Console.WriteLine(Pentagon.Sides); // 5
        Console.WriteLine(Circle.Sides); // Throws NotImplementedException
        Console.WriteLine(Triangle.Sides); // Throws NotImplementedException
    } 
}

public abstract class Shape
{
    public static int Sides { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public new static int Sides { get; set; }
}

public class Pentagon : Shape
{
    public new static int Sides { get; set; }
}


public class Circle : Shape
{ // Circle does not have sides
}

public class Triangle : Shape
{
    // We forget to implement the Sides property
}
```

---

I suppose the static method that use `sides` field is the `CreateFromFile` method which is actually a factory method. I suggest use the factory pattern like this:

```
public interface Shape
{
    int Sides { get; }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public int Sides { get { return 4; } }
}

public class Pentagon : Shape
{
    public int Sides { get { return 5; } }
}

public class ShapeFactory
{
    public static Shape CreateFromFile(string path)
    {
        // your logic to create the shapes
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about a separate factory for it really. That still doesn't completely solved the static issue though. It seems odd that a non-static variable would be needed where, in this example, the number of sides of a pentagon is always 5, for every pentagon that will be created.

Comment: It also prevents using the property to determine which Shape to create, e.g. `if(Rectangle.Sides == loadedInteger) return new Rectangle();`

Comment: Throwing a new implemented exception is a clever workaround that I hadn't thought of. I suppose that ideally it would be able to find that at compile time, but it does still enforce a similar structure to an abstract variable. Thanks!